# How do I print the remainng text?

Tags: java, printing, format, rounding

I finally found out how to print a Double in Java with 2 decimal points. However, I now can't figure out how to keep printing text after the Double is sent out.

I tried to print something like this.

```
double maxTemp;
maxTemp = 5.43210;

System.out.format("\nThe highest Temperature recorded was: %.2f", maxTemp, "*C");
```

Then I wanted it to round the temperature to 2 decimal places and display:

> The highest Temperature recorded was: 5.43*C

However it keeps cutting off the '*C' after the temperature is displayed.
This is the output:

> The highest Temperature recorded was: 5.43

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `"*C"` in the format string, not as an additional argument.

```java
System.out.format("%nThe highest Temperature recorded was: %.2f*C", maxTemp);
```

Alternatively, you can use `%s` for a string placeholder.

```java
System.out.format("%nThe highest Temperature recorded was: %.2f%s", maxTemp, "*C");
```